# Is there any easy way to create oracle partitions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I wnat to add my table some partitions.
Is there any easy way to create partitions on the table that has 5000000 record in oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also searched but i cant find any solution.
You create new table with partitions and transfer data and index .. to the new table
then remove old table and rename new table name with deletede table name

Answer (score 2):

If your table is partitioned, then just

1. add new partitions via `alter table` statement.

If your table is not partitioned and is not in heavy use (i.e. a DB downtime is possible), then

1. create a new table, partitioned
2. copy the data from the old one into the new one
3. create indexes and constraints on the new one
4. drop the old one
5. rename the new one

If your table is in a heavy use, then

1. create a new table, partitioned
2. have a look at the `dbms_redef` package

Comment: Oh damn, lost time typing on a smartphone. Well, bad luck. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try exchange partition ?
Try creating table with partitions and exchange the data from existing table with new table.